# Add div as only child of a node

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to add div as only child to a node. and if that node already has any children make them children of the div.

original DOM looks like:

```
<a href = "">
  <span id="gsp" > </span>
  <span id="gbsp"> some text </span>
</a>
```

I want the output to be:

```
<a href = "">
  <div id="oaa_web_accessibility_highlight">  
    <span id="gsp" > </span>
    <span id="gbsp"> some text </span>
  </div>
</a>
```

instead, below snippet gives me:

```
<a href = "">
  <div id="oaa_web_accessibility_highlight">  </div>
    <span id="gsp" > </span>
    <span id="gbsp"> some text </span>
</a>
```

**I am trying to use the below snippet, but it is not working.**

```
var new_div_element = this.document.createElement('div');
new_div_element.id = 'oaa_web_accessibility_highlight';
node.insertBefore(new_div_element, node.childNodes[0]);
for (var i =0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {  
  if (i == 0) continue;        
  node.childNodes[0].appendChild(node.childNodes[i]);        
}
```

please can anyone help me on this?

Comment: "this" and "node" are not shown/defined in your code sample.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
var new_div_element = document.createElement('div');
new_div_element.id = 'oaa_web_accessibility_highlight';

while (node.firstChild) {  
      new_div_element.appendChild(node.firstChild);        
}

node.appendChild(new_div_element);
```

This empties the children of `node` into `new_div_element`, and then appends `new_div_element` to the now empty `node`.

It doesn't use `innerHTML`, so you're not destroying any state of the elements being transferred.

---

FYI, the reason yours didn't work properly was that your loop is incrementing `i`, but you're removing elements from the `.childNodes` list when you do the `.appendChild`.

Since `.childNodes` is a live list, its content is updated when you move one of its items to a different location. As a result, after the first child is removed, the second child takes its place at that index. Since your `i` is incremented, it skips passed the one(s) that were relocated in the list.

Comment: oh okie thank you. I could see the changes I want on the node. I use Firebug. When I tried to look into the Firebug HTML panel, the text node is deleted on web browser and Firebug shows me: <a><span> </span></a>. no div nothing.

Comment: @user1588142: I don't understand. Are you saying that my code above is removing the text node from inside the `span`? If so, what does `node` represent. I'm assuming it is the outer `<a>` element. If not, then you'll need to tell me what `node` is.

Comment: I think it's the problem with my other function which has to undo what I am doing with the above snippet. I fixed it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use jQuery, it has a `wrapAll` method that does this for you.

```
$(node).children().wrapAll('<div id="oaa_web_accessibility_highlight"></div>');
```